# Clicking Sound From Brakes

Tags: toyota, rattle, clicking

Really annoying one this is.

About two to three weeks ago, out of nowhere. When I apply my brakes whilst moving forward I get an annoying clicking sound ( one time click when applying brakes lightly ). It sounds mainly to be coming inside the car, occasionally with the window down I can hear it slightly outside too. I never hear this noise when the car is stationary or in reverse. Very confusing

Pads and Discs were done about 7 months ago. Calipers and sliders done about 2 months ago.
Did some reading and apparently the cause of this is the pad retainer clips...
So I had them done today, the noise is still there.

Any ideas what it could be ? I'm fairly sure it started after cleaning the car one day. Surely one clean wouldn't remove any lubricant right ?
Only thing I can think of is the pad may have some play in it. Although the mechanic would have picked up on that today if it were the case

It has nothing to do with the rear brake light switch as it never does it when stationary
Thanks

Comment: Before you drive again, make sure all your lug nuts are tight; loose lug nuts can cause a click when braking, but only when in motion.

Comment: Yeah they're all tight

Comment: Sure it is not CV shaft issue? Tried rolling slow and turn/hold hard left and hard right see if you can produce the same sound without braking?

Answer (score 1):

Pads were moving round in the caliper so I got them replaced with higher end ones.  Noise is gone